# Time series classification of different amount of objects / Classification based on trajectory

Tags: classification, time-series

My question is a rather open one, I have a problem that I am looking for solutions or problems that are alike. I know what format the data (which I do not have yet) will take. My goal is to find datasets and models that are similar to this task.

The data is of the following format:

[image: Data]

Over the course of time there are multiple objects, of which I each have features f that include position, size, no image features (but possibly additional information). All objects have the same amount of features. For training I will also know the class (3 classes and one background class), and hopefully its instance (not yet sure whether I will be provided with this information). Each color corresponds to one instance in the table.

During inference I will only be given the features over time, but not matched to their instances. **I want to know as soon as possible (after few time steps), which class the objects belong to**, which I believe can be done based on the trajectory.

1. **What kind of problems are close to this?**
   I thought of cell/molecule trajectory classification, movements of aeroplanes/boats.
2. **What kind of techniques/models should I look for?**
   I thought of RNN/LSTM style ones, but yet am unsure about how well this works if the instances are not matched.

I am happy about any hints and advice. Thank you in advance.